# ReactJs pass props dynamically from array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic, ecmascript-6, srcset

I'm using `srcSet` for changing my images at a certain width. This also works fine but I would like to set the image path/source dynamically instead of hardcoding the values in my source code. Does anyone have any suggestions how I could do this?

For example:

```
this.props.personas[this.state.index].images[0].mediaSize
```

I have a bin available [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn9dHKgYB08U0pHhWra). Feel free to edit it.

Comment: like this? https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn9fGG3QHv_G543dtmR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to iterate through your images:

```
<picture> 
  {this.props.personas[this.state.index].images.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <source
        key={i}
        media={item.mediaSize}
        srcSet={item.imageUrl}
      />
    );
  })}
  <img src={this.props.personas[this.state.index].defaultImage} />
</picture>
```

Check out the full demo below, or a modified version of your bin, [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn9fGG3QHv_G543dtmR).

---

#### Demo

```js
class Personas extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props, context, images) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };
  }

  changePerson  (e, index)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      index: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    const thumbs = this.props.personas.map((current, idx) => {
      return (
        <a key={idx} className={'persona-link ' + (this.state.active ? 'active-link' : '')} >
          <div >
            <img src={current.thumbnail} onClick={(event) => this.changePerson(event, idx)}/>
          </div>
        </a>
      )
    });
    return (
      <div className='personas'>
        <picture> 
          {this.props.personas[this.state.index].images.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <source
                key={i}
                media={item.mediaSize}
                srcSet={item.imageUrl}
              />
            );
          })}
          <img src={this.props.personas[this.state.index].defaultImage} />
        </picture>
        <span className='personas-thumbnail'>
          {thumbs}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<Personas 
     personas =  {[
      {
        thumbnail: '//via.placeholder.com/90x90',
        defaultImage: '//via.placeholder.com/768x400',
        images: [
          {
            imageUrl: '//via.placeholder.com/1024x400',
            mediaSize: "(min-width: 500px)"
          },
          {
            imageUrl: '//via.placeholder.com/1027x400',
            mediaSize: "(min-width: 600px)"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]}
  
  />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

#### Useful links

- [`Array.Prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)
- [Understanding unique keys for array children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js/43892905#43892905)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` on `this.props.personas[this.state.index].images` to create the sources dynamically.

Like this:

```
<picture>         
    {this.props.personas[this.state.index].images.map((el,i) => {
        return  <source
                    key={i}
                    media={el.mediaSize}
                    srcSet={el.imageUrl} 
                />
    })}
    <img src={this.props.personas[this.state.index].defaultImage} />
</picture>
```

Check [working pen](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn9f-HCE5C14_MrtmLH).